# Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error - Importing Frameworks

Tags: objective-c

These frameworks work within another project but when creating a new project, it errors. The new project is blank and it fails because I import the frameworks. I am clicking and dragging the frameworks into Xcode.

Xcode 8.3.2 & Xcode 7.3.1

`Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error Group`

`clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

[image: Screenshot 1]

These are my frameworks:

[image: Screenshot 2]

[Screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsCEr.png)

I have tried:

- Recreating the project
- Readding the frameworks
- Set Build Settings -> Framework Search Paths -> $(PROJECT_DIR) to recursive
- Checked frameworks added to Build Settings -> Link Binary With Libraries
- Clean & Clean Build Folder

Comment: Is there a specific framework which causes the problem? Have you tried adding them one by one and testing the build after each one?

Comment: Can you show the complete error it displays?

Comment: @ManfredScheiner The ExperienceSDK is causing it to fail.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth I uploaded the error as Screenshot 3.

Comment: Ok so it is about the ExperienceSDK. What if you click on the error next to the framework. Any red files in there? Also, have you tried removing and readding the framework?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth I do not see an error next to the framework, what do you mean? I have removed and re-added the framework and have started from scratch adding the frameworks one by one. The files inside the framework do not show any errors.

Comment: Oh dang, typo. I meant the arrow next to the framework. Ok then. Do you use CocoaPods?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth No CocoaPods, I am manually importing the frameworks by dragging and dropping them into a Frameworks Group.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth I re-added the framework and unchecked the target in the section "Add to targets:" and it compiles without error!

Comment: Glad it works now! Just some weird Xcode bugs…

Comment: @LinusGeffarth Thank you for your help!